# Can I run gitlab pipeline stage on a condition?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I know there is a way to run jobs in gitlab pipeline on a condition, but is there a way to do that with a stage? I have a stage which contains many jobs and I don't want to duplicate the code in each of the job definitions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no conditional controls for stages.

However, there are several mechanisms to reduce code duplication in your job definitions, such as YAML anchors, `!reference` tags, `extends:`, etc.